# Scraping div class information using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm having difficulty extracting the div class information from this webpage, https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL.

The income statement data used to have table tag names which wasn't too difficult to extract, but has changed. Below is a sample of the new HTML:

```
<div class="D(tbrg)" data-reactid="44">
<div class="rw-expnded" data-test="fin-row" data-reactid="45">
<div class="D(tbr) fi-row Bgc($hoverBgColor):h" data-reactid="46">
<div class="D(tbc) Ta(start) Pend(15px)--mv2 Pend(10px) Bxz(bb) Py(8px) Bdends(s) Bdbs(s) 
Bdstarts(s) Bdstartw(1px) Bdbw(1px) Bdendw(1px) Bdc($seperatorColor) Pos(st) Start(0) 
Bgc($lv2BgColor) fi-row:h_Bgc($hoverBgColor) Pstart(15px)--mv2 Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="47">
<div class="D(ib) Va(m) Ell Mt(-3px) W(215px)--mv2 W(200px) " title="Total Revenue" data- 
reactid="48"><span class="Va(m)" data-reactid="49">Total Revenue</span>
</div>
<div class="W(3px) Pos(a) Start(100%) T(0) H(100%) Bg($pfColumnFakeShadowGradient) Pe(n) Pend(5px)" 
data-reactid="50"></div>
```

I want to extract the inner text "Total Revenue" from the sample HTML code.

```
Sub financial()

Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

XMLPage.Open "GET", "https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL", False
XMLPage.send
HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

Set HTMLTables = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("d(tbrg)")

With HTMLTables
    For Each HTMLRow In HTMLTables.getElementsByClassName("rw-expnded")
        For Each HTMLCell In HTMLRow.Children
            Debug.Print HTMLCell.innerText
        Next HTMLCell
    Next HTMLRow
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: There are multiple values for Total Revenue - which do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the relationship of the `data-test` attribute with value `fin-col` and its child `span`

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub PrintFinancials()
    Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    XMLPage.Open "GET", "https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL", False
    XMLPage.send
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To 3
        Debug.Print HTMLDoc.querySelectorAll("[data-test=fin-col] span").Item(i).innerText
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: My apologies for the late reply, I thought I would get an email notification when my question was answered. That bit of code is perfect, I've never used HTMLDoc.querySelectorAll before. If I wanted to get the dates on the header, as well as the values on the left column ("Total Revenue", "Cost of Revenue", etc...), what code would I add to incorporate those values? Basically I'm just trying to copy everything in that chart down into an excel database. And thanks again.

Comment: I also wrote an answer in R that works for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58337027/6241235