# How to scraping table using html_table in R if there is no table tag?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest, finance

I have been trying to scrape tables from yahoo.finance, when I inspect and find the required part, there is no table tag in the code. I am able to extract data with html_text function but it doesn't work with html_table function.
[Income Statement](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AVOD.IS/financials?p=AVOD.IS)

[

```html
link <- "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"
link <- paste0(link, tic[2], "/financials?p=", tic[2])
wahis.session <- html_session(link)
p <- wahis.session %>% 
        html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="Col1-1-Financials-Proxy"]/section/div[3]')

p <- html_table(p, header = F, trim = T, fill = T)
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kDW4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discussion at "[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58315274/r-web-scraping-yahoo-finance-after-2019-change][1]" addresses your issue.  Based on the discussion in the link, you can obtain the information as follows for "AAPL":

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

tic <- "AAPL"
link <- "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"
link <- paste0(link, tic, "/financials?p=", tic)
wahis.session <- html_session(link)
p <- wahis.session 
nodes <- p %>% html_nodes(".fi-row")

df = NULL

for(i in nodes){
  r <- list(i %>%html_nodes("[title],[data-test='fin-col']")%>%html_text())
  df <- rbind(df,as.data.frame(matrix(r[[1]], ncol = length(r[[1]]), byrow = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}

matches <- str_match_all(p1%>%html_node('#Col1-1-Financials-Proxy')%>%html_text(),'\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}')   
headers <- c('Breakdown','TTM', matches[[1]][,1]) 
names(df) <- headers
```